# Apache + PHP Mac OS X 10.0 - does it block diskutil usage in shell_exec()?

Tags: php, shell-exec, osx-yosemite

I'm on Mac OS X 10 Yosemite, so I'm wondering if others experience the same problem. This code gives you an insight into the problem. Make an index.php file, and this inside:

```
<?php
$exec = "diskutil list";
echo $exec;
$output = shell_exec($exec);
echo $output;
```

This is when using the built-in Apache + PHP version. When using XAMPP or Nightrain, it has no problem running the command above. So I'm wondering if the Apache or PHP version of OSX blocks certain shell_exec commands?

My experience so far:

When I type in the command-line the following command:

```
diskutil info /dev/disk1s1
```

I get a full overview of the disk information.

But when I use `shell_exec()` to execute the same command in PHP on OSX I get an error:

> Could not find disk: /dev/disk1s1

Apache is configured to use the same ownership as my user (User:staff) - and all other commands work.

Also when I use the following command in the command-line:

```
diskutil list
```

I get a full overview. But then again `shell_exec()` is not returning anything, and in the Apache error log I see:

> Could not start up a DiskManagement session

I Googled and found zero results.

Comment: When I use PHP-Nightrain to run the commands, I don't have the same problems as described above.

Answer (score 0):

First, your command line command is one thing, but the command in your PHP script is another.  Meaning your command line examples are:

```
 diskutil info /dev/disk1s1
```

But the command in your PHP script leaves out the disk `/dev/disk1s1` like this:

```
 diskutil list
```

So unclear what you are doing that is not working. Also, often in PHP scripts you need to set the full path for any binaries that are being called. So instead of this line:

```
$exec = "diskutil info";
```

Change it to this; note I added `/dev/disk1s1` so the command has a disk to act on:

```
$exec = "/usr/sbin/diskutil info /dev/disk1s1";
```

And that is the location of `diskutil` on my Mac OS X 10.9.5 setup. To make sure it would be in the same path, use [`which`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/which) like this:

```
which diskutil
```

Which would return something like this:

```
/usr/sbin/diskutil
```

And when I run it from the command line, I am doing it like this; assuming the test file is named `shell_exec_test.php`:

```
php ./shell_exec_test.php
```

Comment: I tried that - to no avail. It gives the same problem. Also with the fixed command (which I also corrected in the question).

Comment: Sorry, I was editing the question before to list "diskinfo list", but someone else was editing the question as well (admin?) so my question got set back to the original and faulty "diskutil info"